# Delete button on hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having real problem with a hoverIntent.

http://jsfiddle.net/5fwqL/

What I want:

1. When hovering over the text for about **500ms** I want the deletetext to show.
2. If I press the deletebutton i want the text to be deleted
3. If I go out of the text without pressing deletetext I want it to hide()

javascript

```
$(document).on({
mouseenter: function () {
    mouse_is_inside = true;
    $(this).next().slideDown();            
},

mouseleave: function () {
    mouse_is_inside = false;
    $(this).next().hide();   
}
}, '.title');

$('.deleteLink').on('click', function() {
   $(this).prev().remove();         
});
```

html

```
<div>
   <div class='title'>TitleText</div>
   <div class='delete'><a class='deleteLink' href="#">delete...</a></div>
</div>
```

** Forgot to mention that It has to work in IE8, so I have to use old style! **

Comment: Fiddles are fine, but please try to include pertinent code in the question - helpers shouldn't have to click out just to get a feel for the question.

Comment: Can you also explicitly state what the problem is? see updated fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/5fwqL/1/

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon I can't press the "deleteText", and I can't get the delay to work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/42Tw8/

You can use CSS to handle showing and hiding the delete link. Say you nested your HTML like this

```
<div class='title'>
    TitleText 1
    <a class='delete' href="#">delete...</a>
</div>
```

Then you can use CSS like this

```
.delete{
    color: red;
    display: none;
}
.title:hover .delete {
   display:block  
}
```

It's quite a common pattern for things like delete/edit links actually. The **.title:hover .delete** means the CSS the **.delete** will have when a parent **.title** is being hovered on. You could have also added an arbitrary class to your parent  in your example and used that if you wanted to keep the same HTML arrangement.

Then use the JS below to handle the click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Does that make sense? It's slightly differently arranged to your starting point

**EDIT**

For the fade in/out I mentioned in the comment, you could use something like this

```
.delete{
    color: red;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.title:hover .delete {
   opacity: 1;
   transition:opacity 2s linear;
   -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
}​
```

**EDIT2**

Changed the above code to use different transition times for fade in and fade out

Comment: +1, I think this is a more intuitive approach for the user. Replacing the `delete` text with a little red `x` image would also be great.

Comment: Hi, thanks. What if I want to have the "delay" for about 500ms?

Comment: If I'm honest, I just wouldn't add more code for such a short delay. Or maybe just use some CSS to fade them in/out - see http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/42Tw8/1/ I'll update the answer with the snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $(".title").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).data("mouse_hover", true);
            var self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (self.data("mouse_hover") === true) {
                    self.next(".deleteLink").show();
                }
            }, 500);
        },   
        function() {
            $(this).data("mouse_hover", false).next(".delete").hide();
        }        
    );
    $(".deleteLink").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).text("deleted").prev(".title").slideUp(function() {
            $(this).hide();   
        });
    });
});    ​
```